# How can I change the default python on my Ubuntu 20.04 to Python3.8?

Tags: bash, python, bashrc

I would like to set python 3.8 as default on my PC
Thinkpad X230
Ubuntu 20.04

I tried setting an alias

```
gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ alias python='usr/bin/python3.8'
```

Q: Does this alter a .bashrc file?  If so, which?
~/.bashrc?
another?
if so, which?

```
gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ python --version
bash: usr/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory
```

Complains it cannot find /usr/bin/python3.8, buuuuut:

`gt@gt-ThinkPad-X230:~$ ls /usr/bin/python*`

`/usr/bin/python     /usr/bin/python3.8        /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize`
`/usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python3.8-config  /usr/bin/python3-unidiff`
`/usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3-config`
`/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3-futurize`

How do I get bash to find see /usr/bin/python3.8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly to answer your question, your approach should work, I think the path you've given in your alias needs the `/` preceding the path so the command should be:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8'
```

This would indeed need to go into your `~/.bashrc` file assuming you are using bash.

Secondly, Ubuntu has a really nice method of setting default binaries globally rather than messing with dot config files as depicted here: [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html), so a better solution may be to simply run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.8
```

This will ensure you have the version of python in use that you intend, everywhere.

Comment: Thanks!  update-alternatives looks great, but perhaps a bigger gun than I need for a one-man laptop.

Comment: I just tried this (in my case setting 'python' to '/usr/bin/python3' on ubuntu20.04, but got the following error: 'update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python'. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @dagmarPrime `update-alternatives` is exactly what you need, as your aliases won't get called in scripts. `python` can and should point to python 3 for most purposes these days and `update-alternatives` is the right way to do that.

Comment: @MaxPower You're correct; this does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, for the reason you describe. But `sudo apt install python-is-python3` does, per another answer, https://askubuntu.com/a/1272899/379076 .

Comment: After updating from 16 Xenial to 20.04.3 (via 18) alternatives seems to be a little wonky.  alternatives says the symlink is pointing to python3.9 but it isn't.
`update-alternatives --display python3`
  `link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.9`
`link python3 is /usr/bin/python3`
But...
`ls -l /usr/bin/python3` gives
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8` ...ie pointing at 3.8.   `update-alternatives  --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.9`   shows `update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation ... because link group python3 is broken`.

Comment: If you're getting the **update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python** error, then I recommend adding the alternative options as per the answer from @NoirHirsuite: https://askubuntu.com/a/1317470/618745.

Answer (score 54):

The correct way is `sudo apt install python-is-python3` - it effectively does a symlink, but it also keeps pace with future updates; so if your ubuntu distribution moves to say Python 3.9, the manual symlink will no longer work, but the package makes sure it is still valid.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into this when I next upgrade python!

Comment: I did `sudo apt install python-is-python3`, but nothing changed. What are the next steps? No man entry either

Comment: @Abdull inspect your environment. As I wrote, it does not do much more then install a symlink, so perhaps your PATH is messed up, or the binary that the symlink points to has been changed, there can be bunch of other problems. If you are at your wits end, I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: This ensures that the command `python` invokes `python3`. It does not run `python3.8` specifically unless that is the default version of `python3`. If you have multiple versions of `python3.x` installed you may need to use `update-alternatives` to switch between them or set a default.

Answer (score 14):

Check the installed versions of Python:

```bsh
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

Then, create the alternatives:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2
```

Then, choose the version you want:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

You can easily switch between default Python versions.

Comment: We recommend against creating new alternatives in `/usr/bin/` that the OS hasn't provided for you - it may well cause problems on future upgrades.  Somebody else has already pointed to the `python-is-python3` package, which is better in this case.

Comment: Personal preference, since I have no use for python2: use the **python-is-python3** package to ensure that `python` always invokes `python3`. However I do have multiple versions of python3.x installed, so adapting this answer to install each of those as alternatives allows me to set a specific version of python3 as the default: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 8`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me since I have a few python versions.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do it in a command shell by typing:

```
alias python=python3.8
```

To make it permanent you need to open up ~/.bashrc and add that line to the end of it. Should be as simple as that! Keep in mind this only works on a per user basis, which may or may not be what you want.

The other other thing that I notice with your attempt, is that your missing the leading /, so it should be reading as:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8'
```

without that leading forward / it may be trying to use a relative path.

Comment: this is not the solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that I hopes differentiate between using the **python-is-python3** and **update-alternatives** options described in different answers. At first I believed that using BOTH of these options gave me an optimal solution, after testing this for a short while I realized I had a problem.

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)**, running under the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10.

My first observation is that I didn't have **python2** installed at all; I did have **python3.8**, provided as the default "system" Python 3 package for this distro. I noticed that the `python` command didn't work:

```
$ python --version

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

I solved this by installing **python-is-python3**, which creates symlinks in `/usr/bin/`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```

This may be enough, but I have multiple versions of Python 3 installed for... *reasons*. I wanted to be able to choose between different versions of Python 3 so the **update-alternatives** package was useful:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 10
```

The effect of this was (1) to make `python3.10` the default on my system, since it has the highest priority--the number at the end--and (2) allows me to switch the system-wide version of python via:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3

There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.10   10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   10        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    8         manual mode
```

Note that this is using python**3** as the command/alias.

---

Note: I don't recommend using **update-alternatives** to switch (frequently) between different default versions of Python 3.x for your projects. It is better to use virtual environments within each project, installed using an explicit version of Python, e.g.

```
$ python3.8 -m venv .venv
```

---

## UPDATE

Since using the approach described above I have discovered a problem: when trying to upgrade my disto using `apt-get update`, etc. I saw problems such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467521/how-to-fix-error-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-20-04): *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'*.

The cause was that I had changed my default version of `python3` to be `python3.10` and this was incompatible with many system scripts in Ubuntu 20.04, which expected `python3.8`.

Thus I have [reverted my default](https://askubuntu.com/a/1501942/618745) to be `python3.8` and will explicitly use `python3.10` to create venvs for my projects.