# Can't install HP plugin on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

I am trying to connect to an HP M1217nfw MFP via Wi-Fi. The installation says I need an HP plugin for the printer.

`hp-doctor` notes that a required dependency `pyqt5` is missing.

When I start `hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run` I get:

```
error: Unable to load Qt5 support. Is it installed? 
   Try running with -i or --qt3 instead.
```

When I run `sudo ./hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run --qt3,` it tells me there is an unrecognized flag.

If I try to install `python-pyqt5` or `python2-pyqt5` I get:

```
Unable to locate package
```

python3-pyqt5 is installed with the latest version

I have removed and reinstalled HPLIP both from the HP site using several versions from 3.18 to 3.20.9 and by reinstalling HPLIP 3.20 from the Ubuntu repository.

I checked that Python2 was installed with `apt`.

Trying to run `hp-setup` or `hp-plugin` dies with error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Running `lsb_release -a` from the command line produces the correct release information.

It seems I need the HP Plugin and the HP Plugin downloader needs a generic `pyqt5` module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

The suggested solutions involve running `hp-setup` or `hp-plugin`, but I can't as they error out on `lsb_release -a`.

I also can't run `hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run` as it errors out looking for `pyqt5`.

Output of `dpkg -l hplip`:

```
ii  hplip     3.20.3+dfsg0-2 amd64   HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
```

Output of `apt list python3-pyqt5`:

```
python3-pyqt5/focal,now 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5/focal 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 i386
```

Comment: See if installing the package foomatic-db (`apt install foomatic-db`) helps with your ppd problem?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: OK; it was worth a try. By the way, if you can find the ppd file you need, you can simply copy it to `/etc/cups/ppd/`. In the past, I've been able to find an old Ubuntu package (from a previous version of Ubuntu) that had the ppd I needed; I downloaded the corresponding *.deb (from https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and simply extracted the specific *.ppd file I needed.

Comment: pyqt5 is not available in Ubuntu 20.04 and you can't download/install it manually. hplip depends on this package and thus will it not install. Various bug reports have been issued towards the developers of hplip: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bugs?orderby=-id&start=0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) as you need [>3.10.9](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) (use deb-version) with `hp-plugin` installed.

Comment: I do not think the installation says you need an HP ppd file. A plugin, maybe. Edit?

Comment: Hey Gord! Please add the output of `dpkg -l hplip` to your question.

Comment: Can you append your question with the output of `apt list python3-pyqt5`

Comment: Hey Gord! Please do read this article: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 5):

Download a plugin from [the OpenPrinting website](https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/). Install it with `sh PLUGIN_FILENAME`.

Comment: Unfortunately my printer is not listed on the site.

Comment: @Gord Perhaps I am misunderstanding something but hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run is in the list at the link I gave. Then `sh hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run` after downloading.

Comment: As I stated running hplip-3-20-3-plugin.run gives error: Unable to load Qt5 support. Is it installed? Try running with -i or --qt3 instead. and hplip-3-20-3-plugin.run -qt3 gives Invalid flag

Comment: I saw and understood your statement, You are not being advised to run hp-plugin. You really should confirm (or not) that the needed plugin has been downloaded from the link given and say whether `sh hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run` successfully installs the plugin.

Comment: We seem to be talking to cross purposes. Please re-read my statement above the program you are suggesting does not work for me.

Comment: Manual installation of the printer-specific plugin with `sh` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the second best answer needs python3 to run by default for me running `python3 $(which hp-plugin)` fixes the problem and the dialog continues.

Wish i knew what is going on here though...

(ubuntu 20.04 with ColorLaserjet Pro MFP M281fdw here)

Comment: This worked for me with a HP Laserjet 1536dnf MFP. I have no idea why it did though!  :D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I finally solved this, Here is what I did.
First as suggested I updated python to python 3 as described above. This fixed half the problem. Next I downloaded the hplip tarball from
developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

The problem is that in hplip/base/password.py they are still using platform.dist()[0] which was removed in python 3.8

So comment out hplip/base/password.py as follows:

`84 #    try:

85 #        os_name = platform.dist()[0]

86 #    except AttributeError:

87 #        import distro

88 #        os_name = distro.linux_distribution()[0]

89`

or remove the code.
Next go to
https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/

download both the plugin.run and the plugin.run.asc files that match the version of hplip tarball you just downloaded.

Now follow the directions at developers.hp.com for installing the tarball.

Everything now works on my system.

Comment: Ohh good job on solving this and thank you for sharing the answer with our community even after so much time has passed since then!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Realised I'm not using the plugin but the full on HP LIP installer.  The problem I faced sounds the same though, so this might still help you

I faced the same problem over the last couple of days so tried to debug what the installer was doing (I'm using the latest, 3.20.11).

**TL;DR:** The installer is running python2 while I was installing pyqt5 for python3.  I fixed it by running:

```
    $ sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Once I knew that python2 was the issue, I found how to fix it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272870/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-on-my-ubuntu-20-04-to-python3-8)

---

For a bit more detail, by default /usr/bin/python is:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

When I tried to import PyQt5 in python2, it doesn't work:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Aug  4 2020, 11:16:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt5
```

While in python3 it does:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>>
```

After installing the package above, it updates the symlink to point to python3 and there are no more dependency errors:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python3
```

Comment: Thank you. You have solved half my problem. I now have PyQt5 running.

Comment: Unfortunately hp-plugin errors out with the message "lsb_release -a returns a non-zero value." When I run the command manually it says "No LSB modules are available."

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer not to add much to what everything has added, but just to summarize what worked for me.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 `hp-setup` and `hp-plugin` were not working despite having the default Repo installed.

Then downloaded `hplip-3.12.4.run` from there https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

Install `sh hplip-3.12.4.run` failed because of `pyqt5`.
But the below made it work

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
python3
>>> import PyQt5
```

But then `hp-setup` failed to install plugin with error

> lsb_release -a

Then grabbed the plugin matching my hplip version here https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/ as stated by @bryan_p and installed the same way as hplip `sh hplip-3.12.4.plugin.run` and this time it installed properly.

`hp-setup` then ran smoothly