# How to fix error `No module named 'apt_pkg' in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, python

I have a VM running Ubuntu 20.04 inside windows and I tried to fix a problem, and now I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt-pkg'
```

I did run the code

```
sudo apt install python3-apt
```

which did not help. When restarting the VM I get the same error (i.e. I cannot actually open a Terminal on the GUI probably because of that error). I need to change to a non-GUI terminal...

I followed to solution suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg) but the command

```
ls -l | grep apt_pkg
```

did not return anything.

I also tried the answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588066/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-appears-in-various-commands) and I got errors like follows after running the first command `sudo apt remove python3-apt`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Run the following command and choose python3.8:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of built-in/system scripts use the following "shebang" to indicate what binary should run the script. This is expected to be a link to the system-default version of Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 this is expected to be `python3.8` and many scripts assuming that this is the version used when calling `python3`. If you have installed a different version of python then these scripts may fail unexpectedly. You need to ensure that `/usr/bin/python3` points at `python3.8`.

---

One way to do this is to follow the [alternative answer to this question offered by @Alex](https://askubuntu.com/a/1467525/618745) which I elaborate on here. Assuming you have installed **update-alternatives** AND added different versions of Python AND configured one of those to be the default, then this should allow you to choose a different version of python:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

To keep things fixed, you can set `python3.8` to be the default version by (re)adding it to **update-alternatives** with a suitably high priority (I use 100 in the example below).

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 100
```

Re-running the tool with the `--config python3` parameters again should list the alternatives and their priority.