# Trying to upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 but all answers not working

Tags: 20.04, dell

I issued the commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.30.17) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 29, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up unattended-upgrades (2.3ubuntu0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.30.17); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 unattended-upgrades
 update-notifier
 update-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have searched stack exchange but have not been able to find a fix

Comment: The most common reason for `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` is that the version of Python3 is no longer the stock version that came with Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's find out if that's your case: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `apt list python3`

Comment: python3/focal,now 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3/focal 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 i386.  I've removed and reinstalled python3 several times

Comment: Etiquette: "*edit your question*" means just that. Avoid adding information in comments, which are often overlooked or deleted. A good question is the best way to attract useful help.

Comment: I think we lack some important background. Please edit your question to explain more: Why did you need to reinstall Python3 several times? What problem were you trying to solve? What led you to use the "clean" command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error \`No module named 'apt\_pkg' in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467521/how-to-fix-error-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet)

Comment: No.  After re-installing and selecting python 3.8 (previously 3.10). The upgrade started, but failed with error code 1.  Now I cannot start the machine as it cannot load some system libraries. Is there a way to get out of this?